# Reading NetworkStream doesn't advance stream

Tags: c#, stream, networkstream

I have a client-server application where the server transmits a 4-byte integer specifying how large the next transmission is going to be.  When I read the 4-byte integer on the client side (specifying FILE_SIZE), the next time I read the stream I get FILE_SIZE + 4 bytes read.

Do I need to specify the offset to 4 when reading from this stream, or is there a way to automatically advance the NetworkStream so my offset can always be 0?

SERVER

```
NetworkStream theStream = theClient.getStream();

//...
//Calculate file size with FileInfo and put into byte[] size
//...

theStream.Write(size, 0, size.Length);
theStream.Flush();
```

CLIENT

```
NetworkStream theStream = theClient.getStream();

//read size
byte[] size = new byte[4];
int bytesRead = theStream.Read(size, 0, 4);

...

//read content
byte[] content = new byte[4096];
bytesRead = theStream.Read(content, 0, 4096);

Console.WriteLine(bytesRead); // <-- Prints filesize + 4
```

Comment: What is `filesize`? Is it the same as `size.Length`?

Comment: Are you _certain_ that `size.Length` (server-side) is 4? (And that you're not reading the next file's size in that second read on the client side?)

Comment: What is size? What you're doing will be unstable. Use BinaryReader/BinaryWriter instead with ReadInt32/WriteInt32 to avoid sizing issues.

Comment: `NetworkStream` does not support random access to the network data stream. The value of the CanSeek property, which indicates whether the stream supports seeking, is always false; reading the Position property, reading the Length property, or calling the Seek method will throw a NotSupportedException. - From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx).  Perhaps you can read the stream and discard the first 4 bytes when reading the content?

Comment: size is a byte[] obtained via BitConverter.GetBytes(fileInfo.Length); where fileInfo = new FileInfo(myFileName);

Comment: @John you could of course inspect the first bytes of `content` after the read, to see whether you got your file or the prefix. I would also be interested in seeing the server-code that writes the content, to make sure nothing is wrong there.

Comment: btw, your `Read` code still isn't reliable there (although you'll probably fluke it); you cannot assume that an entire chunk is read in one go (i.e. `i += chunkSize`... means nothing, since we might only have read 2 bytes, even in the middle of the file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right; found it; `FileInfo.Length` is a `long`; your call to:

```
binWrite.Write(fileInfo.Length);
```

writes 8 bytes, **little-endian**. You then read that back via:

```
filesize = binRead.ReadInt32();
```

which **little-endian** will give you the same value (for 32 bits, at least). You have 4 `00` bytes left unused in the stream, though (from the high-bytes of the `long`) - hence the 4 byte mismatch.

Use one of:

- `binWrite.Write((int)fileInfo.Length);`
- `filesize = binRead.ReadInt64();`

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkStream` certainly advances, but in both cases, your read is unreliable; a classic "read known amount of content" would be:

```
static void ReadAll(Stream source, byte[] buffer, int bytes) {
  if(bytes > buffer.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bytes");
  int bytesRead, offset = 0;
  while(bytes > 0 && (bytesRead = source.Reader(buffer, offset, bytes)) > 0) {
    offset += bytesRead;
    bytes -= bytesRead;
  }
  if(bytes != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
}
```

with:

```
ReadAll(theStream, size, 4);
...
ReadAll(theStream, content, contentLength);
```

note also that you need to be careful with endianness when parsing the length-prefix.

I suspect you simply aren't reading the complete data.

Comment: @aloneguid the OP is using a `Stream`, and *personally* I prefer to avoid `BinaryReader` (but then, I tend to be very particular about my encoding)

Comment: BinaryReader accepts Stream in constructor as well as source encoding. What's the reason to avoid it?

Comment: @aloneguid mainly because for the things I'm doing, it doesn't add anything useful. The only marginal case is "read known amount of content", which is trivial to repro. Also, the read/write operations do not necessarily agree with your required data format (especially, but not only, relating to endianness). For context, I maintain an OSS binary serialization library, with very specific encoding, which simply doesn't match `BinaryReader` very well ;p

Comment: that's only in your particular case, I think BinaryXXX it saves a few nights when writing a binary protocol from scratch, C# both sides ;)

Comment: @aloneguid if saving a few nights was the goal, a better option would be: to use a pre-rolled binary serialization library ;p (except, maybe, my nights...)