# Can't exit a loop with multiple buffer transfer over TCP/Sockets .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, tcp, stream

I'm transfering data over TCP/Sockets with the .Net (System.Net.Sockets)

I am using this code on client side :

```
tc.SendBufferSize = 4096
Dim fs As New FileStream(wfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim rijn As New RijndaelManaged
Dim cs As New CryptoStream(fs, rijn.CreateEncryptor(CreateKey(key), CreateIV(IV)), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
Dim bytesToSend(tc.SendBufferSize) As Byte
Dim numBytesRead As Integer
Do
      numBytesRead = cs.Read(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length)
      tcp_str.Write(bytesToSend, 0, numBytesRead)
Loop Until numBytesRead = 0
tcp_str.Flush()
cs.Close()
```

And This code on server side :

```
Dim FS As New FileStream(CompleteFileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
Dim CS As New CryptoStream(FS, Rijn.CreateDecryptor(DataExchangeKey, DataExchangeIv), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
Tcp_Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096
Dim bytesToRead(Tcp_Client.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
Dim numBytesRead As Integer = 0
Do
numBytesRead = Tcp_NetStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0,Tcp_Client.ReceiveBufferSize)
CS.Write(bytesToRead, 0, numBytesRead)
Loop Until numBytesRead = 0
Console.WriteLine("Finished")
CS.FlushFinalBlock()
CS.Close()
FS.Close()
```

But the server side doesn't leave the Do/Loop, futhermore it never writes the last buffer and never does the CS.FlushFinalBlock()

Any Ideas Why ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: If your server isn't leaving the `do` loop, it's because `cs.Read` is not returning zero. You don't paste what `cs` is or how it's coded.

Comment: what is `cs` in the client? does the client get out of the loop?

Comment: On the client side cs.read returns 0, when I put a messagebox after it, it shows. (I'll modify my sourcecode on the post to show what is cs on client side)

Comment: in all seriousness - look into the `Using` construct - it would have saved you here, but more importantly: it is *required and expected* that you properly dispose your `IDisposable` objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server won't leave the `Do` loop until the client closes their connection (allowing `Read` to return 0 once the data is all consumed). I suspect, therefore, you just need (at the end of the client code):

```
tcp_str.Close()
```

(*flushing* a stream is very different to formally *closing* it)

If the client doesn't *get* to `tcp_str.Close()`, then check that `cs` (whatever `cs` is) can *also* detect the end of the incoming stream.

Note that all of this would have happened automatically if you had used `Using` - if you just let go of the socket (undisposed) then it will remain open until garbage-collection next fires (and gets around to running the finalizer).

Comment: I've edited my first post, cs is the CryptoStream on the client

Comment: @Bahaïka which is itself pulling from a `FileStream` - so that should be fine, as a file-stream (unlike a network-stream) trivially knows where the end is.

Comment: I would like to keep the stream opened, is there any way to do it ?
Because the stream may be used again for another file transfer ?

Comment: @Bahaïka to do that, you will need to prefix each message with the amount of data that forms the next message (which will mean completing the encryption operation to get the final size). You then make the server code read *exactly* that much by decrementing a counter in the read-loop.

Comment: @Bahaïka funnily enough, pretty much identical to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7907825/23354